# JTextArea updating after KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, refresh, jtextarea, keylistener

I'm making a chat and I'd like to add the possibility for users in a private room to see whenever another user is typing a message.
I'm doing that by sending a message to the server everytime a key is pressed in the JTextArea. If the field is empty and wasn't before, I'm sending a request to not show the message. If the field is not empty but was, I'm asking to show the message.

My problem is that when testing if the JTextArea is empty or not (in my keylistener, btw), the key typed is added to the area AFTER going in the "keyPressed" function, therefore what I want to do is delayed by one character all the time. For example, if I type the first time, nothing happens since textarea.getText().isEmpty() returns true, but if I clear the field after, a message is sent saying that I'm typing a message because the field now contains one character before being removed.

I can probably find a solution to this problem but I want it to be the cleanest possible (maybe just a JTextArea's function call?). Isn't there a way to refresh a JTextArea so that the key pressed is first added to the text field then processed by the listener?

I have the feeling it is impossible but there are so many things I have yet to discover :^)

Comment: So your ultamite goal is to send the event after the letter is displayed? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: I think you need to read this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Comment: What about if the user pastes text into the text area? Instead, take a look at [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners)